# Color adjustment with reference pixel values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First of all, I apologise if this is the wrong place to post this question, but it seems highly mathematical for me so I'm giving it a shot:

I'm trying to build an application where a couple things happen:

- At calibration time, it divides a game board in 24 chunks and grabs the center pixel's color value, saving it for later as a reference pixel.
- At game time, when a piece is placed, it grabs the nearest reference pixel, and also grabs the pixel at the same coordinates that the camera sees. This way I have a means of comparison at how things changed.
- I also have a colour for all pieces that: a) have been calibrated and b) are being placed on the map. These colours are obtained by calculating the mean colour of the whole blob of the piece.

What I need is a way to compare those reference/captured pixels to then transform the piece colour (as it is captured in the camera) to get as close to the calibrated value.

I'm using the YCrCb color space for this, as (from my very limited understanding) it's the best way to work with colours in computer vision.

Any tips on how to do this transformation?

For reference, here's a data sample of what I have. What I need is to get the `Captured` column as close to the `Original` column as much as possible. Again, `Reference Color` is grabbed at calibration time, `Pixel Color`

```
| Piece    | Original      | Captured      | Reference Color | Pixel Color |
| -------- | ------------- | ------------- | --------------- | ----------- |
| Car      | 115, 69, 139  | 29, 155, 124  | 94, 84, 74      | 21, 26, 26  |
| Coal     | 33, 121, 138  | 5, 127, 127   | 94, 84, 74      | 21, 25, 25  |
| Nuclear  | 161, 168, 92  | 45, 154, 108  | 92, 152, 128    | 30, 70, 61  |
| Windmill | 225, 121, 135 | 101, 129, 121 | 92, 152, 128    | 28, 68, 58  |
```

Comment: It may be a mathematical problem, but computer-science is not a mathematical tag. Can you find a suitable mathematical tag? Would algebra-precalculus be suitable?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you obtain those values. I try to place the piece "car". I find the chunk it's placed in and look up the corresponding reference colour. Now, how do I obtain pixel colour and captured colour? Is the pixel colour the colour of the reference pixel after placing the piece?

Comment: I've changed the tags and explained how I obtain the piece colours. Basically, the app works with a BG subtraction algorithm that gives me a blob of where the piece is. I then calculate the mean colour in that blob.

Comment: So your `Captured` column consists of mean values of the piece blobs, right? I'm still not sure what your pixel colours are. Also: Is it correct that you do NOT know the original values and your goal is to extrapolate them from the other columns?

Comment: The `Captured` column is the mean colour of the blob that contains the piece on the map. These pixel colours are represented in the YCrCb colour space. I do have the original values, but I want to extrapolate a "corrected" value from the other columns in order to more accurately predict which value is correct (ie. after "fixing" the colour, it will become closer to a car than coal)

Comment: I think the colour space isn't terribly important for the question. As far as I am concerned it is just a $3$-dimensional space (a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{256}$ or even just a set of $256^3$ elements). I'm still not sure what you want, though. Sorry. :( Why can't you just fix the colour by setting `fixed := original`? As I understand up to now, you want to take the values in the last three columns and compute something close to the first column. Perhaps the question is: What operations are we allowed to use for this?

Comment: It actually is, because each element affects the colour in different ways. The idea is to use the last 3 columns to get a better guess at what object the game actually sees. It's meant to be used in a decision algorithm (ie. what color is this one closest to?)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation, I will think about it and maybe post something later (no time right now). Any answer I may offer will necessarily be heuristic, though. Basically you are asking for an appropriate distance function in your colour space so you can choose the predefined colour closest to your measured colours. Of course, you can always construct examples where such a method fails.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Any methods I've tried so far (been looking at a spreadsheet all afternoon trying different things) have failed. If there's a solution that works for those 3, then it will surely work for everything else.

Comment: @changelog your question is far away from being clear. It might need a major revision.

Comment: Can you explain what's not clear?